# Django foreign key form.save() issue

Tags: django

I am new to Django and trying to create a signup view by using a form with a model extension of User model from `django.contrib.auth.models`  and the UserCreations forms as below however a database error occurred after I submit the signup form in the server:

```
 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (The foreign key)
```

I thought the key will be generated automatically indeed. What is the problem?truly appreciate your help!!
Below is the views:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from .forms import signupform
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        s_form= signupform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid()and s_form.is_valid():
            user =form.save()
            s_form.save()
            login(request,user)


        return redirect("../")
    else:
        form =UserCreationForm()
        s_form = signupform()

    return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form,'s_form': s_form})
```

Here is the forms

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


class signupform(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    F_name = forms.CharField(label=("First Name"))
    L_name = forms.CharField(label=("Last Name"))
    Date_of_birth = forms.DateField()
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'email',
               'placeholder': ('E-mail address')}))
    phone = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("F_name", "L_name", "Date_of_birth", "email")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(signupform, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Here is the models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    F_name =models.CharField(max_length=50 )
    L_name =models.CharField(max_length=50 )
    email=models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=8 )

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance.profile.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here that your `Profile` in the `s_form` still does not refer to a `User` object. Although you create one with signals, this will not update the `Proile` in the `s_form`, since that is a different Python object.

I advise to drop the signals in the `Profile` model, especially since signals are overused, and a lot of Django ORM calls (especially ones in bulk) circumvent the signals anyway. See [this blogpost](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/) for example.

Then you can link the user to the profile in your view:

```
from .forms import signupform

def signup_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        s_form= signupform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid()and s_form.is_valid():
            user =form.save()
            s_form.instance.user = user
            s_form.save()
            login(request,user)
```

So the `Profile` model then looks like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    F_name =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    L_name =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixes the problem :)